# Password checker in c language

Tags: c

I want to take input as a string and evaluate if it is a valid password. The password is valid if it has numbers, capital and small alphabets, and a length of at least 7 characters. Also, when all these requirements are satisfied, the output should be "Strong", else "Weak". Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define N 20

int main()
{
  char pass[N];
  int i, x=0, p;
  printf("Enter a password: ");
  scanf("%s", &pass);
  if(strlen(pass)>=7)
  {
     p=strlen(pass);
     for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
     {
       if ((pass[i] >= 'a' && pass[i] <= 'z') || (pass[i] >= 'A' && pass[i <= 'Z')  || (pass[i] >= '0' && pass[i] <= '9'))
          printf("Sucess! ");
     }
 }  
 else
   printf("Try Again..");
 return 0;
```

}

Somethings are not working like: 1. After execution, it prints "Sucess!!" multiple times.. 2. In the inner if block, when i replace || with &&, it didn't print anything.

Please help.

Comment: 1. Your print statement is in your loop, so it's going to print once for each character that meets the condition. 2. How can a character be a lowercase letter AND an uppercase letter AND a digit at the same time?

Comment: " After execution, it prints "Sucess!!" multiple times". That's because you are doing that print for every letter. Your logic is not correct. You should not declare success until all letters are checked.

Comment: The only way the current code can get "Try Again" is if the password is too short.

Comment: kaylum can you please tell the correct logic..

Comment: BessieTheCow i think it is cheking all elements that if it contains a lowercase AND uppercase AND number.. Sorry ; }

Comment: You can have flags for each critera. e.g. `hasUpper, hasLower, hasNumber, lengthOk`. All of these set to false initially. Then for each character check whether any of those conditions are met for that character and set the corresponding flag if it does. After the loop ends use the flags to evaluate the password strength.

Comment: `strong = (hasUpper && hasLower && hasNumber && lengthOk); weak = !strong;`

Comment: kalyum please tell me bro.. how to check if a string has lowercase letter AND uppercase letter AND numbers..

Comment: kalyum thanks bro.. i'll try it..

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to achieve the same results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change this section of code:

```c
     p=strlen(pass);
     for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
     {
       if ((pass[i] >= 'a' && pass[i] <= 'z') || (pass[i] >= 'A' && pass[i <= 'Z')  || (pass[i] >= '0' && pass[i] <= '9'))
          printf("Sucess! ");
     }
```

... to something like this:

```c
     int lower_case_count = 0;
     int upper_case_count = 0;
     int digit_count = 0;
     p=strlen(pass);
     for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
          if (pass[i] >= 'a' && pass[i] <= 'z') ++lower_case_count;
          if (pass[i] >= 'A' && pass[i] <= 'Z') ++upper_case_count;
          if (pass[i] >= '0' && pass[i] <= '9') ++digit_count;
     }    
     if (lower_case_count > 0 && upper_case_count > 0 && digit_count > 0) {
          printf("Strong\n");
     }
```

In the loop you just want to count how many of each type of characters is present.

Once the loop is done, you can check whether all requirements are satisfied and take appropriate action.

Comment: rtx13 thank you very much bro.. that was exactly what i am looking for.. just tell me one thing please.. if i want to check weather the string has special characters.. how can i do it..?

Comment: You could add another `if` statement inside the loop, something like this: `if (pass[i] == '!' || pass[i] =='@' || pass[i] == '#' || ... ) ++special_count;`

Comment: You're welcome. If you find any answer that solves your problem, please feel free to vote up (▲) and/or accept it (✔︎).

Comment: rtx13 Done.. : )

Comment: The tests for the type of char are depending on the underlying alphabet being ASCII.   This is not always a valid assumption.  Suggest `#include <ctype.h>`  then using tests like: `if( islower( pass[i] )`  `if( isupper( pass[i] )` and `if( isdigit( pass[i] )`  and for the later question: `if( ! isalnum( pass[i] ) )`

Comment: @rtx13 you can also check for the 7 characters minimum in order to fully address the OP. Good answer anyway! I didn't notice the post is pretty old actually ..

Answer (score 1):

You made me thinking and I came up with this rather simple solution - two series of ifs, one wrapped within a while loop. It checks for lower and uppercase, numbers and special characters, reporting the exact error a user had eventually made.

```
//A program for password validation
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>//for islower(), isupper(), isdigit() and ispunct()
#include <string.h>//for strlen()

int main(void)
{
    char pass[30];
    printf("Enter your password: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", pass);//so that password may contain space char
    int i = 0,
    lower_count = 0,
    upper_count = 0,
    digit_count = 0,
    punct_count = 0;
    int length = strlen(pass);
    //loop goes through the password as array
    while (pass[i]) {
        if(islower(pass[i]))//if there is lowercase
            lower_count++;
        if(isupper(pass[i]))//if there is uppercase
            upper_count++;
        if (isdigit(pass[i]))//if there is a number
            digit_count++;
        if (ispunct(pass[i]))//if there is a special chars
            punct_count++;
        i++;
        }
        if(strlen(pass) < 8)
        {
            printf("The password must have at least 8 chars\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if(lower_count == 0)
        {
             printf("You need lowercases\n");
        }
        if(upper_count == 0)
        {
             printf("You need an uppercase\n");
        }
        if(digit_count == 0)
        {
             printf("You need digits\n");
        }
        if(punct_count == 0)
        {
             printf("You need a special character\n");
        }
        if(upper_count != 0 && digit_count != 0 && punct_count != 0 &&
        length > 12)
        {
            printf("Your password is strong!\n");
        }
        if(upper_count != 0 && digit_count != 0 && punct_count != 0 &&
        length <= 12)
        {
            printf("Your password is OK\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**By Using Ctype.h, below code I found very good and easy**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool valid(const char *password);

int main(void)
{
    char password[] = "Password@123";
    if (valid(password))
    {
        printf("Your password is valid!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Your password needs at least one uppercase letter, lowercase letter, number and symbol\n");
    }
}

// TODO: Complete the Boolean function below
bool valid(const char *password)
{
    int length = strlen(password);
    int lower_count = 0;
    int upper_count = 0;
    int digit_count = 0;
    int symbol_count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(islower(password[i])){
         lower_count += 1;
    }
        if(isupper(password[i])){
             upper_count += 1;
        }
        if(isdigit(password[i])){
             digit_count += 1;
        }
        if(ispunct(password[i])){
            symbol_count += 1;
        }
    }

printf("Lower Count: %d\nUpper Count: %d\nDigit Count: %d\nSymbol Count: %d\n", lower_count, upper_count, digit_count, symbol_count);
    if(lower_count != 0 && upper_count != 0 && digit_count != 0 && symbol_count != 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**My Output is below:**

> Lower Count: 7 > Upper Count: 1 > Digit Count: 3 > Symbol Count: 1 >
> Your password is valid!

---